# Bootstrap navbar issue - menu wont show on click

Tags: wordpress, twitter-bootstrap

I have a problem with the navbar on the new site I'm working on. When I make a chrome window smaller as to have my menu turn into a navbar, I cant get the navbar to work. The menus wont show up on click.
I'm working on changing a html5 template into a Wordpress template. The navbar is working on the html5 template, so I have done something to scew up the navbar when coding for WP.

Can it be script related or css related? The actual code has not been change.

Anyone got any ideas?

Comment: Check if any div is overlapping over it. I had faced same problem. It was a div which covered my nav section.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please make sure you added this (.js) in correct order and you point right to the folder that you put them in:

1- jquery library

2- js for bootstrap 3

**example:**

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

you can check to see if the files is loaded or not ( e.g: In Google Chrome ) :

- Right click in your page and select ( **Inspect elements** )
- Chose ( **Resources** )
- in the left panel you will see folder icon with name depend on your folder name open it and lock for ( **Scripts** )
- under this menu you will see the loaded .js files for your site, make sure that ( **jquery library and bootstrap js** ) is loaded.

hope this will help you

Comment: The inspect elements was a great suggestion. Thank you! I figured it would be something with the scripts and yes, no scrips were loaded correctly.

From your jquery link I was able to get the jquery to work, but the bootstrap one isnt working as it should :(

I tried using:
 <script src="<?php get_template_directory(); ?>/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
But that didnt work, nor did:
<script src="<?php get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/js/bootstrap.js"></script>

Any thoughts why it's not working?

Comment: Ok, now I got it! I was using the wrong php code to get the template url...LOL, sorry for asking such a basic question. Thank you for your help. I really appreciate it!

Comment: happy that your problem solved @Hemskis, please consider making the question answer done so anyone face a problem like this could know the solution.